# powershell $erroractionpreference overrides -erroraction

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a user with a new-mailbox command.  I need to wait for it to create and replicate so when I try to set-aduser -description command it actually finds an account.

I have seen the sleep -seconds but would rather look at a true test and then execute type method.

I have set the erroractionpreference to stop in the beginning of my script. But thought I can change it on each command if i want.

-EA Test #1 Fails $erroractionpreference = "stop" and -Erroraction SilentlyContinue

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>     $erroractionpreference = "stop"
Do {
   Sleep -seconds 1
   $UserExists = Get-aduser notavaliduser -Erroraction SilentlyContinue |fw IsValid
   write-host "." -NoNewline
   }
While (!$UserExists)

Get-aduser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'notavaliduser' under: 'DC=XXX,DC=local'.
At line:4 char:22
+        $UserExists = Get-aduser notavaliduser -Erroraction SilentlyContinue |fw  ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (notavaliduser:ADUser) [Get-ADUser],        ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,
Microsoft.Acti    veDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

-EA Test #2 Works $erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue" and no -Erroraction

```
   PS C:\Windows\system32>    $erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue"
Do {
   Sleep -seconds 1
   $UserExists = Get-aduser notavaliduser  |fw IsValid
   write-host "." -NoNewline
   }
 While (!$UserExists)

 ...............................
```

-EA Test #3 Fails.  $erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue" and -Erroraction Stop

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue"
    Do {
    Sleep -seconds 1
    $UserExists = Get-aduser notavaliduser -Erroraction Stop |fw IsValid
    write-host "." -NoNewline
    }
    While (!$UserExists)


    .........
```

Why does the $erroractionpreference work but -erroractionpreference seems to be totally ignored.

Is it ok to just change the variable from stop and then put it back after this bit executes? Seems like a rig.

$erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue"
Script 
$erroractionpreference = "stop"

Comment: I was able to get it to work without throwing an error if not found by adding a filter.                                                               PS C:\Windows\system32>   $erroractionpreference = "stop"
       Do {
       Sleep -seconds 1
       $UserExists = Get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq "notavaliduser"} |fw IsValid
       write-host "." -NoNewline
       }
    While (!$UserExists)
    
    ...

Comment: The Do While command is just hanging for some reason.

Comment: I think its working this way...(Get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq $EffSamId}) |fw IsValid

Comment: From the looks of the docs, the argument is of type ADUser. I suspect what is happening is that the error occurs when converting the string "notavaliduser" into this ADUser type. That is why the ErrorAction parameter has no effect. The error occurs before the cmdlet is called.