# -ErrorAction argument ignored in favor of $ErrorActionPreference

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Both, [`$ErrorActionPreference`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx) variable and [`-ErrorAction`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) cmdlet argument should define behavior for [non-terminating errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878319(v=vs.85).aspx).

Since variable is global and argument is specific to cmdlet invocation I expect that argument overrides variable. In fact, I can't find a situation, where `-ErrorAction` does anything at all.

```
$expression = 'Write-Error "non-terminating error"'

# No exception
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
Invoke-Expression -Command $expression

# Exception
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Invoke-Expression -Command $expression

# No exception, why?
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
Invoke-Expression -Command $expression -ErrorAction Stop

# Exception, why?
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Invoke-Expression -Command $expression -ErrorAction Continue
```

P.S. - I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976132/powershell-erroractionpreference-overrides-erroraction) but it is more focused on related issue rather on priority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-ErrorAction` parameter applies to errors generated by the command it is applied to. In the case of `Invoke-Expression (iex)` that means errors encountered while preparing to invoke the passed expression or errors encountered post processing the results. It doesn't, however, apply to the expression/command itself.

In the OP if you apply `-ErrorAction` to the `Write-Error` command you will get the expected results, whether or not you use `iex`.

Comment: You right, I was just confused with behavior of `Invoke-Expression`. I thought it would be logical if `-ErrorAction` would affect results of expression execution too.